# Removal of everything except mesh, or extraction of mesh from Blender file to a new one

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, rigging

I want to have just the mesh part of the character I downloaded from [here.](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/71055) I don't want any of the UV-mapping, materials, rigging, and stuff. 
I'll add that stuff later with my own materials. In any case, I can't seem to delete everything. The old stuff is messing with the new stuff; it's like I have to go really deep to remove everything.

Answer (score 1):

Open your downloaded file, create a cube, name it "onlyMesh", go to the mesh tab in the properties panel, switch the cube mesh to the character mesh, delete the whole original character, save, close, reopen your file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be easily accomplished in the outliner editor window. This is the small window at the far right of the default screen, stacked on top of the properties editor window. In a new instance of Blender, or at least in a new scene, click File > Open to open the file browser. In the left hand column, in the "Open Blender file" pane, uncheck "Load UI". Now, navigate to the location of the downloaded file, and open it.

Pull down on the border between these Outliner editor window and the Properties editor window to enlarge the Outliner editor window. The outliner editor window will have a list of several items, a listing for a camera, a listing for a lamp, a listing for a cube (unless you've deleted it), and a listing for your downloaded character. To the left of each item is a small circle containing a "+" sign. Click on this circle to the left of your downloaded character, and several items should appear below the name of the downloaded character. The first one contains the name of the mesh of the object, but you will note that this, too, has a circle containing a plus sign at the far right side of the line. Click this circle, and you will see other entries, including "materials", and other items. Left clicking on each line in the outliner window below the line containing the name of the mesh, in the resulting context menu, select "delete". This will delete that data link from the file. When you've deleted all items below the line containing the name of the mesh, you will be left with an object containing your mesh.

BTW, for what it's worth, I find the outliner window to be so useful that I have modified my default screen so that at the far right are two windows the full height of the screen—one for the outliner window, and beside it one for the properties editor window.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new blender file and select the default cube.
Then *append* the mesh (and only the mesh) you want from the other blender file (shift+F1 / file menu).

Now go to the Object data tab in the properties panel (small triangle) and select the appended mesh instead of the default "Cube" mesh. You should rename the cube object too in the object tab.

Save your file and press *Revert* in the file menu to get rid of the unused Cube mesh.

This way you only use the mesh and get rid of all the unwanted stuff (screwed scene-, world- and render settings, linked or packed images or textures and so on).

For further studies read here: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/index.html